# What does a greyed out eyeball symbol with a strike through it mean?

Tags: support, tags

[image]

I've never seen this symbol next to 'performance' before. What does it mean? Was it something I did? And why is this question greyed out (I assume it's related.)

I thought perhaps hovering over the symbol would give me a hint (like hovering over the vote buttons) but there's no hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you've selected "ignore tag". Presumably unintentionally?

If you click on the tag, you'll get to a page where you can unignore it.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. It was unintentional. It's unusual that ignoring a tag would still have the question shown in the list though :) seems to defeat the point somewhat

Comment: @knol There is a setting to hide (questions with) ignored tags, but it's disabled by default. A feature that makes stuff invisibly vanish has poor discoverability, so should only be made available to those who know about it.